# solr multiple sorting does not work as expected

Tags: solr, solr4

My documents has 2 indexed attribute - name (string) and version (number)
I want within the same score the documents will be displayed by the following order

score(desc),name(desc),version(desc)

Therefor I query using :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/vault/select?
           q=BOM&fl=*:score& 
           sort=score+desc,Name+desc,Version+desc
```

And I get the following inside the result:

```
<doc>
   <str name="Name">BOM Total test2</str>
   ...
   <int name="Version">2</int>
   ...
   <float name="score">2.2388418</float>
</doc>
<doc>
   <str name="Name">BOM Total test - Copy</str>
   ...
   <int name="Version">2</int>
   ...
   <float name="score">2.2388418</float>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="Name">BOM Total test2</str>
  ...
  <int name="Version">1</int>
  ...
  <float name="score">2.2388418</float>
</doc>
```

The scoring is equal, but the name is not sorted.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:
schema definitions

```
 ....
 <field name="Name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
 <field name="Version" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
 ....
```

Comment: How have you defined the fields in your schema?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at all of the token filters, analyzers, etc. that are being applied in the `text_en` fieldType, that makes it less than ideal for sorting. For sorting of string values, you are going to be better off using a specific fieldType for sorting. In the past I have used the following fieldType for sorting of string fields.

```
 <fieldType name="lowercase_sort" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

The Solr Example schema also includes the following fieldType for sorting:

```
 <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" 
     sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
         input string is preserved as a single token
      -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
         when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
      -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <!-- The PatternReplaceFilter gives you the flexibility to use
         Java Regular expression to replace any sequence of characters
         matching a pattern with an arbitrary replacement string, 
         which may include back references to portions of the original
         string matched by the pattern.

         See the Java Regular Expression documentation for more
         information on pattern and replacement string syntax.

         http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
      -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then define an additional field for sorting, maybe like the following:

```
 <field name="Name_Sort" type="lowercase_sort" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

use a copyField to populate this field

```
 <copyField src="Name" dest="Name_Sort"/>
```

Then sort on this new `Name_Sort` field in your query.

Comment: Exactly why I asked what the fields were. In addition you might want to debug the query with debug=true and look at what the analyzed text looks like in the admin panel (usually at: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/<your_core_name>/analysis)